# Can I avoid required svn add [dir] on branch?

Tags: svn

SVN seem to require me to run

```
svn add [dir]
```

if I add a directory in local branch (and whats it to be versioned).
Can I make SVN more clever than this default behavior?

Or is the easiest approach to run

```
svn add .
```

in project root before any commit?

regards,
//t

edit:

```
svn add --force ./*
```

that is..

Comment: When you say "local branch", do you mean "working copy"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subversion will not track a file unless you instruct it to. That's by design and I think it's a good design: it sounds more intuitive to select stuff you want into version control (something that needs to be done once) than to un-select stuff you don't want (which you'd possibly need to do on every commit ever).

Said that, you might feel more comfortable with a GUI tool since most graphical clients allow to add and commit in a single step.

Comment: Ok. More intuitive for me would be if new files in non-ignored direcories would be versioned without separate action needed. Thanks anyway.